# What is more effective seeking luggage damage compensation from the aiport or airline?

Tags: luggage, compensation, geneva, easyjet, damaged-luggage

We found air luggage to be damaged after a flight and reported the damage right at the airport. The airport then advised us to seek damage compensation from the airline as this would go more smoothly but as this is a low budget airline I highly doubt it.

Which option will be more effective?

Comment: Would you like to reveal which airline and/or airport? Did you have any insurance that might cover it?

Comment: It is Geneva Airport (GVA) and EasyJet. No insurance to cover it. (Maybe there is one on my credit cards as a bonus that I am not aware of.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [easyJet's Carrier Regulations](http://www.easyjet.com/EN/Book/regulations.html?utm_source=ej_CMS&utm_medium=EN_Homepage&utm_term=CarrierRegs&utm_content=StaticLink&utm_campaign=Footer#lostbaggage):

> If your baggage is damaged, lost or delayed during an easyJet flight,
>   you must advise a member of easyJet ground handling staff at the
>   airport of arrival immediately.
>
> **In the event of loss or damage to baggage the airline's liability is
>   normally limited to a maximum of 1,000 [Special Drawing Rights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Drawing_Rights)
>   (approximately £820**).

Essentially, it doesn't matter whether your airline is low-cost or full-service. (If I'm not wrong) They have minimum obligations for carriage that they must adhere to as declared in their terms and conditions. Baggage handling falls under the purview of airlines and that's whom you must seek compensation from.

In your case, you will have to contact EasyJet but they may argue that baggage damage was not notified to them at the airport, thus allowing them to claim they were not responsible for it. If you have travel insurance of some sort, then it could cover compensations. Alternatively, check if your credit/debit card has travel insurance included.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that some $ cards include a type of insurance that you might not even realize you have.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that compensation for lost or damaged luggage is always with the airline who flies the last leg of your journey. I've never heard of an airport dealing with luggage issues.